# After heroku run rake db:migrate (cedar stack) - migration not happening

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, dbmigrate

I'm trying to run **heroku run rake db:migrate**, but I get the following:

```
  Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.7
```

And that's it - Migration is not happening!

Although I have set up everything alright - development as sqlite3 and production as pg.
And previously all the migrations worked just fine. (rails 3.1. app )

I'm not sure what is happening here.

Here are the logs:

```
  ←[35m2012-01-08T11:25:22+00:00 app[run.8]:←[0m Awaiting client
  ←[35m2012-01-08T11:25:22+00:00 app[run.8]:←[0m Starting process with command `bu
  ndle exec rake db:migrate`
  ←[35m2012-01-08T11:25:22+00:00 heroku[run.8]:←[0m State changed from starting to
  up
  ←[35m2012-01-08T11:25:35+00:00 heroku[run.8]:←[0m State changed from up to compl
  ete
  ←[35m2012-01-08T11:25:35+00:00 heroku[run.8]:←[0m Process exited
```

I don't see any errors.

Has anybody came across with something similar ?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what `run` is... I always use `heroku rake db:migrate`.

Comment: run is correct - you use run on cedar stack applications.

Comment: see what the output of (heroku run) rake db:version on both your local and heroku applications to see what the latest migration that was run actually is.

Answer (score -1):

The reason for this was simply because the migration has already happened automatically after pushing the updated app to heroku.